# Why is $F(\zeta_n)/F$ Galois?

Tags: field-theory

> Why is $F(\zeta_n)/F$ is Galois.

If $F$ is arbitrary field, and $\zeta_n$ a primitive n-th root of unity then why it is Galois, I know all the roots of $X^n-1$ lie in the extension field but what does it mean for the normality. I mean if $F$ were finite then it would be a splitting field of $X^n-1$, so normal (by a theorem) but here $F$ can be also infinite and separability is also a problem

EDIT: OK Separability issue has been solved, but normality not yet

Comment: Hint: A polynomial $f$ is separable over $F$ iff $(f,f') = 1 \in F[X]$.

Comment: @Watson I know that theorem, but how to apply here ?

Comment: Try to answer the following questions: what is $f'$ ? What are the polynomials $g$ that divides $f'$ in $F[X]$? What are such $g$ that divides $f$?

Comment: @so it would contradict the irreducibility or minimality of the polynomial ?, The problematic case is only if $F$ is infinite of finite characteristic

Comment: You see that you need to assume $(n, \text{char}(F))=1$ to ensure separability.

Comment: @Watson so it separable if and only if the condition you've written holds ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumme that $(n, char(F))=1$. We have that $x^n-1$ splits in $F(\zeta_n)$, so by a theorem (see chapter 9, section 9.2 of Stewart's book "Galois Theory") $F(\zeta_n)/F$ is normal. Now, $(x^n-1)'=nx^{n-1}$ and then $(x^n-1, nx^{n-1})=1$. So $F(\zeta_n)/F$ is separable and hence galoisian.

Comment: Aha I knew that theorem but I've falsely assumed that the field is finite, not the extension, thanks a lot